# How to structure code when need to enable GPS

Tags: android, gps, android-asynctask, code-structure

My code works fine if the GPS is enabled, but when it needs to be enabled it force crashes. Something to do with trying to get the location when the GPS is not enabled. I try to open up Settings for the user to enable GPS but it just continues trying to record GPS (hence force-crashing).

I don't know when and where to call Main.

First `StartupSettings` is called:

```
public class StartupSettings extends Activity{
    boolean hasGps = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startup_dialog);
        checkGPS();
    }

    public void checkGPS()
    {
        LocationHandler2 lh = new LocationHandler2();

        hasGps = lh.enableGPS(this);


        if (hasGps == true)
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkGPSConnection);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }


    }
```

The `enableGPS()` method called by the `StartUpSettings() Activity` above:

```
public class LocationHandler2{
    LocationManager mlocManager;

    public boolean enableGPS(final StartupSettings main)
    {    
        mlocManager = (LocationManager)main.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(!mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            //Ask the user to enable GPS
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(main);
            builder.setTitle("Location Manager");
            builder.setMessage("Would you like to enable GPS?");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //Launch settings, allowing user to make a change
                    Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    main.startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //No location service, no Activity

                    main.finish();
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
        }   
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I want to then call `Main` which starts up an `AsyncTask` called `StartProcess()`

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pages);


        StartProcess sProcess = new StartProcess();
        sProcess.execute(this);
    }
```

The `StartProcess AsyncTask`:

```
public class StartProcess extends AsyncTask<Main, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Main... params) {


        LocationHandler2 lh = new LocationHandler2();
        try {
            lh.getLocationStartEnd(params[0],0);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Logcat:

```
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider==null
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.java:653)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at mfc.generalguixapi8.LocationHandler2.getLocationStartEnd(LocationHandler2.java:120)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at mfc.generalguixapi8.StartProcess.doInBackground(StartProcess.java:13)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at mfc.generalguixapi8.StartProcess.doInBackground(StartProcess.java:1)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-26 17:33:31.264: E/AndroidRuntime(10560):    ... 4 more
02-26 17:34:37.694: E/global(10620): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
02-26 17:34:37.694: E/global(10620): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
02-26 17:34:37.694: E/global(10620):    at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
02-26 17:34:37.694: E/global(10620):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
02-26 17:34:37.694: E/global(10620):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
02-26 17:34:37.694: E/global(10620):    at mfc.generalguixapi8.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:36)
02-26 17:36:18.134: E/global(10713): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
02-26 17:36:18.134: E/global(10713): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
02-26 17:36:18.134: E/global(10713):    at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
02-26 17:36:18.134: E/global(10713):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
02-26 17:36:18.134: E/global(10713):    at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
02-26 17:36:18.134: E/global(10713):    at mfc.generalguixapi8.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:36)
```

Comment: Your GPSProvider=null ,Are check in real Device

Comment: I know it's null. But the point is, the code is carrying on into the AsyncTask even though I'm trying to let the user enable the GPS i.e. while the user is trying to enable GPS, Main is being executed which calls the AsyncTask. I don't know how to restructure it so it waits for the user to finish enabling GPS.

Comment: I think GPS LocationManager have Method like onGPSEnabled....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the `enableGPS()` method to my `StartupSettings` activity, and then used `startActivityForResult()` to start `Main` when the user enables the GPS.

Not sure if that's ideal but solved!

Answer (score 0):

Yow lady, I dont know whats your problem, but for GPS I did this tutorials http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6 and it works fine, no crashing. For tutorials I do not know which exactly, they should be a little over 100. You must just find tutorials for GPS, this is 30 min of tutorials to do. I hope this is it?